# OpenGL Pin PBO memory

Tags: opengl, pbo

Is it possible to pin a PBO for read and/or write to system memory? Ideally it would be nice to avoid having to synchronize with glMapBuffer and glUnmapBuffer, and use some other way to send the frame via DMA to/from system memory to the GPU.

Comment: [Persistent mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Persistent_mapping)?

Comment: What do you mean by "pin" a buffer?